# docker entrypoint.sh not have the permission of root

Tags: linux, bash, docker

Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

ADD entrypoint.sh /usr/local/bin/
RUN chown root:root /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod 4755 /usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT ["entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

ulimit -n 5000000
```

```
docker build -t test .
docker run -it --rm --name testE test bash
```

result:
/usr/local/bin/entrypoint.sh: line 3: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted

How to resolve the problem?

Comment: You are trying to modify the ulimit of the the host or of the container?

Comment: The issue is likely that the 'nofile' hard setting in the /etc/security/limits.conf is less than what you are trying to set.

Answer (score -1):

you can do it in parameter

```
docker run -it --ulimit nofile=1024:1024  --rm --name testE test bash
```

Click [set-ulimits-in-container](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#set-ulimits-in-container---ulimit)